# 400 error when making post request to Spring server

Tags: swift, spring, alamofire

Hi I'm very new to Swift and trying to make a simple application.

I'm using 'alamofire 5 beta 6' to make a request.

Here is some code below

-code for making  post  request

```
 var json:JSON = JSON(["id":id.text, "password":enteredPassword])

    var parameters: Parameters = ["id":id.text, "password":enteredPassword]


    let headers:HTTPHeaders = [ "Content-Type":"application/json"]

    AF.request("http://127.0.0.1:8080/user", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers).responseJSON{
        response in


        print("response : \(response)")
    }
```

-code for Spring Framework

```
    @RequestMapping(value="user", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public JSONObject addUser(
            @RequestBody Memberinfo member,
            HttpServletRequest request) {


        JSONObject result = new JSONObject();

        return result;
    }
```

-Memberinfo.java that is used in controller to retrieve @RequestBody

```
public class Memberinfo {

String id;
String password;
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
}
```

In Swift code, I set parameter id and password to retrieve it back in Spring framework.

However, right after I make a request, Alamofire  responses with message

```
response : success({
error = "Bad Request";
message = "JSON parse error: Unrecognized token 'id': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'id': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 4]";
path = "/user";
status = 400;
timestamp = "2019-06-09T05:46:07.417+0000";
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the parameter should be sent as following

```
var parameters: Parameters = {"id":id.text, "password":enteredPassword}
```

Another important thing that you don't need to have a JSONObject as a response type for your endpoint you can just annotate your endpoint with @ReponseBody to have a json response

```
@RequestMapping(value="user", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<JSONObject> addUser(
        @RequestBody Memberinfo member,
        HttpServletRequest request) {


    JSONObject result = new JSONObject();

    return result;
}
```

Always use something like Postman or RestClient to test your endpoint before calling this endpoint from an external source